# RewriteCond Simple Issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need the URl http://mydomain.com/careers to go to http://mydomain.com/#!/careers

For what it's worth I've tried numerours variations around this with no success

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/careers$
RewriteRule (.*) /#!/careers [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "!" in your `RewriteCond` line means "not"...
2. Also, "[QSA,L]" means:
   `L` means this is *last rule* (processing terminates after matching this one) and
   `QSA` means *query string append*
   But, becase `R` flag was not specified, this is done by sub-request and not a redirect, so the actual URL in your browser does not change...

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/careers$
RewriteRule (.*) /#!/careers [R,L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I was doing something dumb!

On thing to add though is that the above escapes the # so just adding NE sorts this, my finished rule is as follows:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/careers$
RewriteRule (.*) /#!/careers [R=301,NE]